# How to login Django server using Retrofit in android?

Tags: java, android, django, retrofit

Hi I just created an interface as below:

```
public interface UserClient {

    @POST("login")
    Call<UserInfo> login(@Body Login login);

}
```

UserInfo Class:

```
public class UserInfo {
private String token;

public String getToken(){
    return token;
}

public void setToken(String token){
   this.token = token;
  }
}
```

And here is the main code:

```
Retrofit.Builder builder = new  Retrofit.Builder()         
 .baseUrl("http://amirhoseinbidar.pythonanywhere.com/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

    UserClient userClient = retrofit.create(UserClient.class);
    Login login = new Login("plantdg", "1234");

    Call<UserInfo> userCall = userClient.login(login);
    userCall.enqueue(new Callback<UserInfo>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<UserInfo> call, Response<UserInfo> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "connection successful " +
                        response.body().getToken(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                textView.setText(response.raw().toString());
                //The message is : Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=500, message=Internal Server Error, url=http://amirhoseinbidar.pythonanywhere.com/login}
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<UserInfo> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

So the problem is response is not successful. Anyone can Help?

note: Login class contains two vars (username, password) and a constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I posted raw data type to server instead of form data type. so I did some little changes in the interface:

```
@Headers( "Content-Type: application/json" )
@POST("login/")
Call<UserInfo> login(@Body JsonObject login);
```

note: Backslash was important for me.

and I used a method that returns a JsonObject:

```
private JsonObject returnRaw() {

    JsonObject gson = new JsonObject();

    try {

        JSONObject jsonObj_ = new JSONObject();
        jsonObj_.put("username", "plantdg");
        jsonObj_.put("password", "1234");
        JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
        gson = (JsonObject) jsonParser.parse(jsonObj_.toString());

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return gson;
}
```

And in the main code I passed the returnRaw() as the parameter to the login method:

```
Call<UserInfo> userCall = userClient.login(returnRaw());
```